# Java:Android - Server socket EOFException with Objectstream

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm rather new to server sockets, trying to learn how to code a socket (ive had past experience with using sockets like winsock but this is my first time actually coding one in java).

This is the error I keep getting:

```
Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: 0
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

This is the code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    ServerSocket MyService = null;
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    Integer clientNum = 0;
    Integer inputID, outputID;

        try {
            MyService = new ServerSocket(hidden);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {

            clientSocket = MyService.accept();

            ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());


            Float inputFloat = null;
            Float outputFloat = null;

            Protocol protocol = new Protocol();

            outputFloat = protocol.processFloatInput(null);

            while(true) {
                if(input.readObject().getClass().equals(inputFloat.getClass())) {
                    System.out.println("true");
                    if ((inputFloat = input.readFloat()) != null) {
                        outputFloat = protocol.processFloatInput(inputFloat);
                        output.writeObject(outputFloat);
                        System.out.println("Float value = " + inputFloat);

                    }
                    input.close();
                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                }
                if(input.readObject().getClass().equals(Integer.TYPE)) {
                    if ((inputID = input.readInt()) != null) {
                        outputID = protocol.processIntegerInput(inputID);
                        output.writeObject(inputID);
                        System.out.println("Client " + outputID + " connected.");

                    }
                    input.close();
                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                }
            }

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host: hostname");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Error printed
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: " + clientNum);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }   


};
```

In past tests, i was able to connect to the server, but since I want to check the input data type before operating, I get this.

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EOFException just means you got to the end of the stream. It's normal.

Your problem is that you're reading twice for every object written: once to get its class and again to get the object. You don't get the same object again, you get the next object, so you run out eventually.

You need to store the result of readObject() in a variable, then test its class, then cast it appropriately.